# How to I separate numbers?

Tags: numbers, combinations

How do I separate a combination of numbers AND move them into specific cells based on their variable?

For instance Cell A! contains the numbers: `3, 4, 10, 58, 26`
Title tabs are: `0>2 3-18 19-54 55+`

I want each number for over 10,000 lines to be moved so that I do not have to do it manually. Is there a way?

I've tried to what if but I am not an expert on this particular kind of problem.

Comment: 1: is this in Excel? 2: are all the numbers in a single column?

Answer (score 0):

If this is in Excel and your table looked something like this at the start

```
#A   0>2 3-18 19-54 55+
3
4
10
58
26
```

Try putting something like this in each cell under each title, then copy all the way to bottom of columns.

```
=IF(AND(A1>0 ,A1<3),A1,0)
=IF(AND(A1>2 ,A1<19),A1,0)
=IF(AND(A1>18 ,A1<54),A1,0)
=IF(AND(A1>54),A1,0)
```

Result will be the number in col A1 moves or a 0